# How to Paginate loaded relation with Laravel API resources

Tags: laravel, api, pagination, resources, laravel-pagination

I need to load model relations in it's resource and paginate them.

In my case i have `Category` and `Path` models, plus `CategoryResource` and `PathResource`

The `toArray` method of `CategoryResource` is like below:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id'   => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'slug' => $this->slug,
        'order' => $this->order,
        'paths' => PathResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('paths'))
    ];
}
```

and `toArray` method of `PathResource` is like below:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

**Question** is how can i load and paginate related `Path`'s in my `CategoryResource`?

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding the problem? I am also struck in the same issue and could not find the answer

Comment: @LizeshShakya i posted an answer for this question.

Comment: I'm in the same boat but I wonder if it smells like we're going about this the wrong way. Maybe the paginated relation should actually just be available as its own paginated collection resource with a query to limit it to its relation. E.g. in this case we should have a /paths endpoint which shows a paginated PathResource collection limited to those in the requested Category.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and solved it this way:

**Prerequisites**

You must have/create a resource for `Path` model i.e. `PathResource`
to create one use this command:

`php artisan make:resource PathResource`

**Solution**

The solution is to use laravel `paginate` on relation and use `transform` method on the paginated collection to convert it's items to your resource.

**First Step**

Create a base class for paginating any resource in your app, using this command:

`php artisan make:resource PaginatedCollection -c`

Edit the `PaginatedCollection` and add following codes:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class PaginatedCollection extends ResourceCollection
{

    /**
     * An array to store pagination data that comes from paginate() method.
     * @var array
     */
    protected $pagination;

    /**
     * PaginatedCollection constructor.
     *
     * @param mixed $resource paginated resource using paginate method on models or relations.
     */
    public function __construct($resource)
    {

        $this->pagination = [
            'total' => $resource->total(), // all models count
            'count' => $resource->count(), // paginated result count
            'per_page' => $resource->perPage(),
            'current_page' => $resource->currentPage(),
            'total_pages' => $resource->lastPage()
        ];

        $resource = $resource->getCollection();

        parent::__construct($resource);
    }

    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     * now we have data and pagination info.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            // our resources
            'data' => $this->collection,

            // pagination data
            'pagination' => $this->pagination
        ];
    }
}
```

**Second Step**

make a collection resource for your model and extend `PaginatedCollection`
instead of default `ResourceCollection`.

Run this command to do so:
`php artisan make:resource PathCollection -c`

Now edit your new collection class `PathCollection` and override `toArray` method:

```
/**
 * Transform the resource collection into an array.
 *
 * In this method use your already created resources
 * to avoid code duplications
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [

        // Here we transform any item in paginated items to a resource

        'data' => $this->collection->transform(function ($path) {
            return new PathResource($path);
        }),

        'pagination' => $this->pagination,
    ];
}
```

**Final Step**

In your `CategoryResource` use `PathCollection` like this:

```
return [
    'id'   => $this->id,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'slug' => $this->slug,
    'order' => $this->order,
    'paths' => new PathCollection(
        new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $this->whenLoaded('paths'),
            $this->paths_count,
            10
        )
    ),
];
```

and make sure you import `LengthAwarePaginator` class:
`use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;`

**Usage**

```
$category = Category::with('paths')->withCount('paths')->find(1);
return new CategoryResource($category);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably checkout the documentation on Resources and ResourceCollections. ResourceCollections will allow you to easily paginate your resources. [Api Resource Collection Pagination Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#pagination)

Comment: The documentation only shows how you can paginate a whole model. The question is how can you paginate a relation of the model inside the resource in the toArray method?